# Sorting KDB table while excluding Total row

Tags: kdb

I have noticed when using xasc capital letters take precedence over lower case.

Trying to exclude Total from being considered when doing the sort, wanting to avoid using "lower" then recapitalizing it again. I have my solution below but its rather poor code

`` t:flip (`active`price`price2)!(`def`abc`xyz`hij`Total;12j, 44j, 468j, 26j, 550j;49j, 83j, 716j, 25j, 873j) ``

Thinking there's a better way than this

`` (`active xasc select from t where not active=`Total),select from t where active=`Total ``

Answer (score 4):

Although it does not match the sort order of your example answer, if you're looking to sort by true lexicographical order excluding captials you could do the following:

```
q)t:([]active:`def`abc`xyz`hij`Total;price:12 44 468 26 550;price2:49 83 716 25 873)
q)t iasc lower t`active
active price price2
-------------------
abc    44    83
def    12    49
hij    26    25
Total  550   873
xyz    468   716
```

Otherwise, if you're looking to have the `Total` row at the bottom following the sort then you will need to append it after doing so - given your example table:

```
q)(select[<active]from t where active<>`Total),select from t where active=`Total
active price price2
-------------------
abc    44    83
def    12    49
hij    26    25
xyz    468   716
Total  550   873
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a much cleaner way to do it, but this approach ensures Total is at the bottom without needing two selects (but it needs a group and a sort)

```
q)raze`active xasc/:t group`Total=t`active
active price price2
-------------------
abc    44    83
def    12    49
hij    550   873
xyz    26    25
Total  468   716
```

Answer (score 1):

Matthew's is probably the best all-round solution.

If you know `Total` is always going to end up first after the sort then:

```
{1_x,1#x}`active xasc t // sort, join the first row to the end, drop first row
```

is a pretty concise solution - this is obviously not ideal if you don't have control over the `active` column contents as other uppercase entries would make this unpredictable.